# how to convert a mutating trigger to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER planning_trig BEFORE
    UPDATE OF planned_remediation_date ON evergreen
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    planned_remediation_date DATE;
BEGIN
    SELECT
         planned_remediation_date
    INTO planned_remediation_date
    FROM
        evergreen
    WHERE
            hostname = :new.hostname
        AND instance_name = :new.instance_name
        AND product_home = :new.product_home
        AND it_service = :new.it_service
        AND sw_name = :new.sw_name;
    IF
        planned_remediation_date IS NOT NULL
        AND planned_remediation_date > trunc(sysdate)
    THEN
        UPDATE evergreen
        SET
            planning_status = 'planned';
    ELSE
        UPDATE evergreen
        SET
            planning_status = 'overdue';
    END IF;
END;
/
```

After an update of the row in my table `evergreen` I get this error:

```
ORA-04091: table PTR.EVERGREEN is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
```

I believe the error comes from the fact that I'm trying to update the very same table the trigger is firing on. I read that the best way to handle updates in the same table are stored procedures but I'm quite new to oracle and don't know how to achieve that. Another possibility I heard is `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION Pragma` but not sure either if this applies to my case.

A little more background, the underlying table has a composite unique key `(hostname,instance_name,product_home,it_service,sw_name)` and I want to update an existing column on this table called `planning_status` based on the updated value of `planned_remediation_date`. If that value is not null and greater then today then update with `planned` else `overdue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression `planned_remediation_date IS NOT NULL` is redundant. `planned_remediation_date > trunc(sysdate)` is never TRUE when `planned_remediation_date` is NULL.

Your trigger can be written much shorter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER planning_trig 
    BEFORE UPDATE OF planned_remediation_date ON evergreen
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :new.planned_remediation_date > trunc(sysdate) THEN
       :new.planning_status := 'planned';
    ELSE
       :new.planning_status := 'overdue';
    END IF;
END;
/
```

I guess you like to modify the updated row, not other rows in that table. Otherwise you would need a procedure or a [COMPOUND trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-8A0DA171-BE6A-4798-A1A4-677B88EA16A0)

Comment: yes I want to modify the updated `planned_remediation_date` row. So is it possible to use triggers `on` a table and update that same table ? if instead I would user `after` keyword this would not work right ?

Comment: `AFTER` would not work, because at the moment when the trigger runs the table is already updated and you cannot modify it anymore (within the ROW level trigger)

Comment: so even though the table is not updated yet, I can still access the new value that will update the row with `:new` , is that right ?